# SSHing into WSL2 of a remote Windows 10 from Windows 10

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh, wsl-2

I am planning on using VS Code to work out of WSL2 installed on a remote machine. Before doing that, I wanted to check the direct connectivity from a Windows 10. I followed the instructions given in this [blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-easy-way-how-to-ssh-into-bash-and-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine). Also, the remote Windows 10 is on a VPN.

When I use the command `ssh <username>@<IP address>`, I get the message
`kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset`

Is there anything I am missing to get the connection going?